# Limit flex item height in a flexbox layout

Tags: css

I am trying to create a flexbox layout like shown in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nutrina/c19t88cn/14/).
This is the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    header
  </div>
  <div class="content">
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    footer
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the CSS:

```
.container {
  background-color: green;
  height: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex: 0 0 50px;
}

.content {
  background-color: blue;
  flex: 0 0 90%;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.footer {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 0 0 40px;
}
```

And it works, but I would also limit the size of the entire layout not extend  beyond the '.container' elements fixed height.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks,
Gerald

Comment: I am not clear you question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make `.content` fill the entire allowed space within the container by adding `flex: 1;` property to it.

Working Example:

```js
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  $(".content").append("<div>hello " + i + "</div>");
}
```

```css
.container {
  background-color: green;
  height: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border:3px solid black;
}

.header {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex: 0 0 50px;
}

.content {
  background-color: blue;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.footer {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 0 0 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    header
  </div>
  <div class="content">
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    footer
  </div>
</div>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/0aumg6b0/

Answer (score 0):

replace the old container code in the stylesheet with this one and see if it works

```
    <style>
        .container {
            background-color: green;
            height: 300px;
            max-height: 300px;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            overflow: auto;
        }

        .header {
            background-color: yellow;
            flex: 1;
            overflow: scroll;
            height: 100px;
        }

        .content {
            background-color: blue;
            flex: 7;
            overflow: scroll;
        }

        .footer {
            background-color: red;
            flex:1;
        }

    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate, quae beatae esse, impedit est distinctio ducimus dignissimos suscipit similique quos labore libero ab molestiae, velit eveniet, quo. Odit, architecto, totam!
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit nisi temporibus, rem fugiat dolorum aliquid aspernatur quibusdam quam aut nihil et dignissimos animi minima laboriosam ipsum culpa quisquam repellat eum!
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate, quae beatae esse, impedit est distinctio ducimus dignissimos suscipit similique quos labore libero ab molestiae, velit eveniet, quo. Odit, architecto, totam!
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit nisi temporibus, rem fugiat dolorum aliquid aspernatur quibusdam quam aut nihil et dignissimos animi minima laboriosam ipsum culpa quisquam repellat eum!
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate, quae beatae esse, impedit est distinctio ducimus dignissimos suscipit similique quos labore libero ab molestiae, velit eveniet, quo. Odit, architecto, totam!
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit nisi temporibus, rem fugiat dolorum aliquid aspernatur quibusdam quam aut nihil et dignissimos animi minima laboriosam ipsum culpa quisquam repellat eum!
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate, quae beatae esse, impedit est distinctio ducimus dignissimos suscipit similique quos labore libero ab molestiae, velit eveniet, quo. Odit, architecto, totam!
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit nisi temporibus, rem fugiat dolorum aliquid aspernatur quibusdam quam aut nihil et dignissimos animi minima laboriosam ipsum culpa quisquam repellat eum!
        </div>
        <div class="content">
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            footer
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The overflow:auto does not help me, it only makes the entire layout scrollable ... And I only want to have the content scrollable while having the total height limited to .container.

Comment: check the edited answer..I have added some dummy text to show the <header> scroll..the issue probably was insufficient text to get the scroll going..lemme know if that was what you needed..